# Gradio website doesn't open on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, legacy, gradio

When I try to access my gradio website (that I'm hosting off my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop), it just opens to a blank page on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop.

I tried opening it on chromium and firefox and I get the same behavior. I'm assuming that the older browsers don't support gradio webpages, but wanted to check here and see if anyone else is seeing this behavior, or if someone is able to get this to work. I can access the webpage on every other device I have.